# Redirect subdomain to a site on a different server

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, subdomain

I have a site set up on www.mydomain.com. I'm writing a new application that resides on a different computer on my network and want to have my test users to go to test.mydomain.com to access the new site. Currently I access the test site by going to a different port at www.mydomain.com:8080. How do I configure IIS so that when users go to test.mydomain.com it brings up the new site?

I have my DNS set such that www.mydomain.com and test.mydomain.com both go to the old site. I need to tell IIS to use the test server for all the requests that start with test.mydomain.com.

I've shared the folder over the internal network and as I had said before port 8080 is open on the firewall and mapped to port 80 on the test server. I've set up a new site in IIS on the production server and have it pointing to the network share and IIS is able to authenticate and see the new site, however when I go to test.mydomain.com it still shows the old page.

Answer (score 0):

Just to level set--

1. You have two ASP.NET applications running on the same machine. One is intended to serve content for www.yourdomain.com and the other is meant to serve content for test.yourdomain.com
2. The two ASP.NET application, obviously, live in different folders, and have different IIS application names. You didn't say what they were, but for the sake of example I shall assume the application names are TestApplication and ProductionApplication, with matching virtual directory names.
3. You want all traffic to go to the one box. If the host that the user typed into the URL is www.yourdomain.com, the request should be handled by ProductionApplication; otherwise it is handled by TestApplication.

So in terms of routing...

- A request for https://www.yourdomain.com/page should actually be handled by https://www.yourdomain.com/ProductionApplication/page
- A request for https://test.yourdomain.com/page should actually be handled by https://www.yourdomain.com/TestApplication/page

Am I understanding the requirements?

If so, it's easy to do with an IIS redirect rule, which you can set in web.config.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="AnyName" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.yourdomain.com$" />
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/TestApplication/" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="\TestApplication\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This tells IIS that whenever it receives a request for test.yourdomain.com, it is to modify the URL and insert "TestApplication" before the path that was provided.

For production you'd do something very similar:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="AnyName" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.yourdomain.com$" />
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/ProductionApplication/" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="\ProductionApplication\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Detailed instructions can be found on [Scott Forsyth's Blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-url-rewrite-hosting-multiple-domains-under-one-site).

Comment: No, the test application resides on a different server on the same network. I redirect the requests to the test server at the firewall. If the requests come in on port 8080 then the requests are redirected to the test server.

Comment: (1) What does the redirect header look like? Wouldn't a redirect to `test.yourdomain.com` just resolve to the same old IP address and end up at the same server? Or did you mean *route* instead of redirect? (2) Is the test application clever enough to insert 8080 into all of its absolute links and redirects?

Comment: There is no redirect header. Right now any requests that come in on port 80 go to the production server. Any requests that come in on port 8080 go to the test server. The links are all relative so nothing is being redirected.

Comment: Sounds like a routing issue then. Need to check F/W logs, do a tracert, or wireshark it.  Could be as simple as stale DNS entry.

Comment: Thank you. You were correct it was indeed a DNS issue, along with setting the permissions of the application pool.

Comment: Ha! Occasionally I get lucky.